# Set a maximum for data grouping in Highstock charts to prevent from grouping

Tags: highcharts

I'm working on stockcharts from Highcharts, specially on data grouping. Actually everything works good but I have a question about the max Unit for grouping.

My Data is in month based and I want a grouping on year base if the time range gets greater (i.e. the chart show data for more than 10 years).
The grouping works good, but if the showing Data Range gets bigger Highcharts proceed data grouging and group 2 or 3 years together. I just want the max. "group-size" is one year.

```
// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    alignTicks: false
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    //selected: 1
  },

  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Volume'
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'AAPL Stock Volume',
    dataGrouping: {
      groupPixelWidth: 45,
      units: [[
        'month',
        [1]
      ], [
        'year',[]
      ]]
    },
    data: [[1514764800000, 5250.0], [1517443200000, 5250.0], [1519862400000, 5250.0], [1522540800000, 5250.0], [1525132800000, 5250.0], [1527811200000, 5250.0], [1530403200000, 5250.0], [1533081600000, 5250.0], [1535760000000, 5250.0], [1538352000000, 5250.0], [1541030400000, 19416.6666666667], [1543622400000, 19416.6666666667], [1546300800000, 19566.6666666667], [1548979200000, 19566.6666666667], [1551398400000, 19566.6666666667], [1554076800000, 19566.6666666667], [1556668800000, 19566.6666666667], [1559347200000, 19566.6666666667], [1561939200000, 19566.6666666667], [1564617600000, 19566.6666666667], [1567296000000, 19566.6666666667], [1569888000000, 19566.6666666667], [1572566400000, 19920.833333333365], [1575158400000, 19920.833333333365], [1577836800000, 20075.333333333365], [1580515200000, 20075.333333333365], [1583020800000, 20075.333333333365], [1585699200000, 20075.333333333365], [1588291200000, 20075.333333333365], [1590969600000, 20075.333333333365], [1593561600000, 20075.333333333365], [1596240000000, 20075.333333333365], [1598918400000, 20075.333333333365], [1601510400000, 20075.333333333365], [1604188800000, 20438.3541666667], [1606780800000, 20438.3541666667], [1609459200000, 20597.489166666703], [1612137600000, 20597.489166666703], [1614556800000, 20597.489166666703], [1617235200000, 20597.489166666703], [1619827200000, 20597.489166666703], [1622505600000, 20597.489166666703], [1625097600000, 20597.489166666703], [1627776000000, 20597.489166666703], [1630454400000, 20597.489166666703], [1633046400000, 20597.489166666703], [1635724800000, 20969.585520833367], [1638316800000, 20969.585520833367], [1640995200000, 21133.494570833365], [1643673600000, 21133.494570833365], [1646092800000, 21133.494570833365], [1648771200000, 21133.494570833365], [1651363200000, 21133.494570833365], [1654041600000, 21133.494570833365], [1656633600000, 21133.494570833365], [1659312000000, 21133.494570833365], [1661990400000, 21133.494570833365], [1664582400000, 21133.494570833365], [1667260800000, 21514.893333854197], [1669852800000, 21514.893333854197], [1672531200000, 21683.719655354198], [1675209600000, 21683.719655354198], [1677628800000, 21683.719655354198], [1680307200000, 21683.719655354198], [1682899200000, 21683.719655354198], [1685577600000, 21683.719655354198], [1688169600000, 21683.719655354198], [1690848000000, 21683.719655354198], [1693526400000, 21683.719655354198], [1696118400000, 21683.719655354198], [1698796800000, 22074.65338745055], [1701388800000, 22074.65338745055], [1704067200000, 22248.544498595555], [1706745600000, 22248.544498595555], [1709251200000, 22248.544498595555], [1711929600000, 22248.544498595555], [1714521600000, 22248.544498595555], [1717200000000, 22248.544498595555], [1719792000000, 22248.544498595555], [1722470400000, 22248.544498595555], [1725148800000, 22248.544498595555], [1727740800000, 22248.544498595555], [1730419200000, 22649.251573994316], [1733011200000, 22649.251573994316], [1735689600000, 22828.359418473665], [1738368000000, 22828.359418473665], [1740787200000, 22828.359418473665], [1743465600000, 22828.359418473665], [1746057600000, 22828.359418473665], [1748736000000, 22828.359418473665], [1751328000000, 22828.359418473665], [1754006400000, 22828.359418473665], [1756684800000, 22828.359418473665], [1759276800000, 22828.359418473665], [1761955200000, 23239.084170757396], [1764547200000, 23239.084170757396], [1767225600000, 23423.565250571126], [1769904000000, 23423.565250571126], [1772323200000, 23423.565250571126], [1775001600000, 23423.565250571126], [1777593600000, 23423.565250571126], [1780272000000, 23423.565250571126], [1782864000000, 23423.565250571126], [1785542400000, 23423.565250571126], [1788220800000, 23423.565250571126], [1790812800000, 23423.565250571126], [1793491200000, 23844.558121661954], [1796083200000, 23844.558121661954], [1798761600000, 24034.573633870095], [1801440000000, 24034.573633870095], [1803859200000, 24034.573633870095], [1806537600000, 24034.573633870095], [1809129600000, 24034.573633870095], [1811808000000, 24034.573633870095], [1814400000000, 24034.573633870095], [1817078400000, 24034.573633870095], [1819756800000, 24034.573633870095], [1822348800000, 24034.573633870095], [1825027200000, 24466.09132673819], [1827619200000, 24466.09132673819], [1830297600000, 721711.8073043126], [1832976000000, 24661.807304312577], [1835481600000, 24661.807304312577], [1838160000000, 24661.807304312577], [1840752000000, 24661.807304312577], [1843430400000, 24661.807304312577], [1846022400000, 24661.807304312577], [1848700800000, 24661.807304312577], [1851379200000, 24661.807304312577], [1853971200000, 24661.807304312577], [1856649600000, 18384.531042781764], [1859241600000, 18384.531042781764], [1861920000000, 18384.531042781764], [1864598400000, 18384.531042781764], [1867017600000, 18384.531042781764], [1869696000000, 18384.531042781764], [1872288000000, 18384.531042781764], [1874966400000, 18384.531042781764], [1877558400000, 18384.531042781764], [1880236800000, 18384.531042781764], [1882915200000, 18384.531042781764], [1885507200000, 18384.531042781764], [1888185600000, 18837.894318851308], [1890777600000, 18837.894318851308], [1893456000000, 317154.560985518], [1896134400000, 18904.560985517975], [1898553600000, 18904.560985517975], [1901232000000, 18904.560985517975], [1903824000000, 18904.560985517975], [1906502400000, 18904.560985517975], [1909094400000, 18904.560985517975], [1911772800000, 18904.560985517975], [1914451200000, 18904.560985517975], [1917043200000, 18904.560985517975], [1919721600000, 19369.258343489255], [1922313600000, 19369.258343489255], [1924992000000, 19369.591676822587], [1927670400000, 19369.591676822587], [1930089600000, 19369.591676822587], [1932768000000, 19369.591676822587], [1935360000000, 19369.591676822587], [1938038400000, 19369.591676822587], [1940630400000, 19369.591676822587], [1943308800000, 19369.591676822587], [1945987200000, 19369.591676822587], [1948579200000, 19369.591676822587], [1951257600000, 19845.90646874315], [1953849600000, 19845.90646874315], [1956528000000, 19846.24146874315], [1959206400000, 19846.24146874315], [1961712000000, 19846.24146874315], [1964390400000, 19846.24146874315], [1966982400000, 19846.24146874315], [1969660800000, 19846.24146874315], [1972252800000, 19846.24146874315], [1974931200000, 19846.24146874315], [1977609600000, 19846.24146874315], [1980201600000, 19846.24146874315], [1982880000000, 20334.46413046173], [1985472000000, 20334.46413046173], [1988150400000, 20334.80080546173], [1990828800000, 20334.80080546173], [1993248000000, 20334.80080546173], [1995926400000, 20334.80080546173], [1998518400000, 20334.80080546173], [2001196800000, 20334.80080546173], [2003788800000, 20334.80080546173], [2006467200000, 20334.80080546173], [2009145600000, 20334.80080546173], [2011737600000, 20334.80080546173], [2014416000000, 20835.22903372327], [2017008000000, 20835.22903372327], [2019686400000, 20835.56739209827], [2022364800000, 20835.56739209827], [2024784000000, 20835.56739209827], [2027462400000, 20835.56739209827], [2030054400000, 20835.56739209827], [2032732800000, 20835.56739209827], [2035324800000, 20835.56739209827], [2038003200000, 20835.56739209827], [2040681600000, 20835.56739209827], [2043273600000, 20835.56739209827], [2045952000000, 21348.506326066352], [2048544000000, 21348.506326066352], [2051222400000, 21348.846376233225], [2053900800000, 21348.846376233225], [2056320000000, 21348.846376233225], [2058998400000, 21348.846376233225], [2061590400000, 21348.846376233225], [2064268800000, 21348.846376233225], [2066860800000, 21348.846376233225], [2069539200000, 21348.846376233225], [2072217600000, 21348.846376233225], [2074809600000, 21348.846376233225], [2077488000000, 21874.608783550506], [2080080000000, 21874.608783550506], [2082758400000, 21874.950533968215], [2085436800000, 21874.950533968215], [2087942400000, 21874.950533968215], [2090620800000, 21874.950533968215], [2093212800000, 21874.950533968215], [2095891200000, 21874.950533968215], [2098483200000, 21874.950533968215], [2101161600000, 21874.950533968215], [2103840000000, 21874.950533968215], [2106432000000, 21874.950533968215], [2109110400000, 22413.857001468426], [2111702400000, 22413.857001468426], [2114380800000, 22414.200460638225], [2117059200000, 22414.200460638225], [2119478400000, 22414.200460638225], [2122156800000, 22414.200460638225], [2124748800000, 22414.200460638225], [2127427200000, 22414.200460638225], [2130019200000, 22414.200460638225], [2132697600000, 22414.200460638225], [2135376000000, 22414.200460638225], [2137968000000, 22414.200460638225], [2140646400000, 22966.579589825946], [2143238400000, 22966.579589825946], [2145916800000, 22966.92476629159], [2148595200000, 22966.92476629159], [2151014400000, 22966.92476629159], [2153692800000, 22966.92476629159], [2156284800000, 22966.92476629159], [2158963200000, 22966.92476629159], [2161555200000, 22966.92476629159], [2164233600000, 22966.92476629159], [2166912000000, 22966.92476629159], [2169504000000, 22966.92476629159], [2172182400000, 23533.113373709002], [2174774400000, 23533.113373709002], [2177452800000, 23533.46027605698], [2180131200000, 23533.46027605698], [2182550400000, 23533.46027605698], [2185228800000, 23533.46027605698], [2187820800000, 23533.46027605698], [2190499200000, 23533.46027605698], [2193091200000, 23533.46027605698], [2195769600000, 23533.46027605698], [2198448000000, 23533.46027605698], [2201040000000, 23533.46027605698], [2203718400000, 24113.80359865983], [2206310400000, 24113.80359865983], [2208988800000, 24114.152235519545], [2211667200000, 24114.152235519545], [2214172800000, 24114.152235519545], [2216851200000, 24114.152235519545], [2219443200000, 24114.152235519545], [2222121600000, 24114.152235519545], [2224713600000, 24114.152235519545], [2227392000000, 24114.152235519545], [2230070400000, 24114.152235519545], [2232662400000, 24114.152235519545], [2235340800000, 24709.004141187463], [2237932800000, 24709.004141187463], [2240611200000, 24709.354521231475], [2243289600000, 24709.354521231475], [2245708800000, 24709.354521231475], [2248387200000, 24709.354521231475], [2250979200000, 24709.354521231475], [2253657600000, 24709.354521231475], [2256249600000, 24709.354521231475], [2258928000000, 24709.354521231475], [2261606400000, 24709.354521231475], [2264198400000, 24709.354521231475], [2266876800000, 25319.07772454109], [2269468800000, 25319.07772454109], [2272147200000, 25319.429856485323], [2274825600000, 25319.429856485323], [2277244800000, 25319.429856485323], [2279923200000, 25319.429856485323], [2282515200000, 25319.429856485323], [2285193600000, 25319.429856485323], [2287785600000, 25319.429856485323], [2290464000000, 25319.429856485323], [2293142400000, 25319.429856485323], [2295734400000, 25319.429856485323], [2298412800000, 25944.396139877677], [2301004800000, 25944.396139877677], [2303683200000, 25944.750032481632], [2306361600000, 25944.750032481632], [2308780800000, 25944.750032481632], [2311459200000, 25944.750032481632], [2314051200000, 25944.750032481632], [2316729600000, 25944.750032481632], [2319321600000, 25944.750032481632], [2322000000000, 25944.750032481632], [2324678400000, 25944.750032481632], [2327270400000, 25944.750032481632], [2329948800000, 26585.3404729588], [2332540800000, 26585.3404729588], [2335219200000, 26585.696135025777], [2337897600000, 26585.696135025777], [2340403200000, 26585.696135025777], [2343081600000, 26585.696135025777], [2345673600000, 26585.696135025777], [2348352000000, 26585.696135025777], [2350944000000, 26585.696135025777], [2353622400000, 26585.696135025777], [2356300800000, 26585.696135025777], [2358892800000, 26585.696135025777], [2361571200000, 27242.30133651487], [2364163200000, 27242.30133651487], [2366841600000, 27242.658776892178], [2369520000000, 27242.658776892178], [2371939200000, 27242.658776892178], [2374617600000, 27242.658776892178], [2377209600000, 27242.658776892178], [2379888000000, 27242.658776892178], [2382480000000, 27242.658776892178], [2385158400000, 27242.658776892178], [2387836800000, 27242.658776892178], [2390428800000, 27242.658776892178], [2393107200000, 27915.679108418502], [2395699200000, 27915.679108418502], [2398377600000, 27916.0383359977], [2401056000000, 27916.0383359977], [2403475200000, 27916.0383359977], [2406153600000, 27916.0383359977], [2408745600000, 27916.0383359977], [2411424000000, 27916.0383359977], [2414016000000, 27916.0383359977], [2416694400000, 27916.0383359977], [2419372800000, 27916.0383359977], [2421964800000, 27916.0383359977], [2424643200000, 28605.884175812178], [2427235200000, 28605.884175812178], [2429913600000, 28606.24519952927], [2432592000000, 28606.24519952927], [2435011200000, 28606.24519952927], [2437689600000, 28606.24519952927], [2440281600000, 28606.24519952927], [2442960000000, 28606.24519952927], [2445552000000, 28606.24519952927], [2448230400000, 28606.24519952927], [2450908800000, 28606.24519952927], [2453500800000, 28606.24519952927], [2456179200000, 29313.33718533911], [2458771200000, 29313.33718533911], [2461449600000, 29313.70001417479], [2464128000000, 29313.70001417479], [2466633600000, 29313.70001417479], [2469312000000, 29313.70001417479], [2471904000000, 29313.70001417479], [2474582400000, 29313.70001417479], [2477174400000, 29313.70001417479], [2479852800000, 29313.70001417479], [2482531200000, 29313.70001417479], [2485123200000, 29313.70001417479], [2487801600000, 30038.469299629873], [2490393600000, 30038.469299629873], [2493072000000, 30038.83394260973], [2495750400000, 30038.83394260973], [2498169600000, 30038.83394260973], [2500848000000, 30038.83394260973], [2503440000000, 30038.83394260973], [2506118400000, 30038.83394260973], [2508710400000, 30038.83394260973], [2511388800000, 30038.83394260973], [2514067200000, 30038.83394260973], [2516659200000, 30038.83394260973], [2519337600000, 30781.722460201203], [2521929600000, 30781.722460201203], [2524608000000, 30782.088926395958], [2527286400000, 30782.088926395958], [2529705600000, 30782.088926395958], [2532384000000, 30782.088926395958], [2534976000000, 30782.088926395958], [2537654400000, 30782.088926395958], [2540246400000, 30782.088926395958], [2542924800000, 30782.088926395958], [2545603200000, 30782.088926395958], [2548195200000, 30782.088926395958], [2550873600000, 31543.549656927207], [2553465600000, 31543.549656927207], [2556144000000, 31543.917955452936], [2558822400000, 31543.917955452936], [2561241600000, 31543.917955452936], [2563920000000, 31543.917955452936], [2566512000000, 31543.917955452936], [2569190400000, 31543.917955452936], [2571782400000, 31543.917955452936], [2574460800000, 31543.917955452936], [2577139200000, 31543.917955452936], [2579731200000, 31543.917955452936], [2582409600000, 32324.41520424747], [2585001600000, 32324.41520424747], [2587680000000, 32324.785344265827], [2590358400000, 32324.785344265827], [2592864000000, 32324.785344265827], [2595542400000, 32324.785344265827], [2598134400000, 32324.785344265827], [2600812800000, 32324.785344265827], [2603404800000, 32324.785344265827], [2606083200000, 32324.785344265827], [2608761600000, 32324.785344265827], [2611353600000, 32324.785344265827], [2614032000000, 33124.79502428022], [2616624000000, 33124.79502428022], [2619302400000, 33125.16701499867], [2621980800000, 33125.16701499867], [2624400000000, 33125.16701499867], [2627078400000, 33125.16701499867], [2629670400000, 33125.16701499867], [2632348800000, 33125.16701499867], [2634940800000, 33125.16701499867], [2637619200000, 33125.16701499867], [2640297600000, 33125.16701499867], [2642889600000, 33125.16701499867], [2645568000000, 33945.17693701342], [2648160000000, 33945.17693701342], [2650838400000, 33945.55078768546], [2653516800000, 33945.55078768546], [2655936000000, 33945.55078768546], [2658614400000, 33945.55078768546], [2661206400000, 33945.55078768546], [2663884800000, 33945.55078768546], [2666476800000, 33945.55078768546], [2669155200000, 33945.55078768546], [2671833600000, 33945.55078768546], [2674425600000, 33945.55078768546], [2677104000000, 34786.06095775059], [2679696000000, 34786.06095775059], [2682374400000, 34786.43667767599], [2685052800000, 34786.43667767599], [2687472000000, 34786.43667767599], [2690150400000, 34786.43667767599], [2692742400000, 34786.43667767599], [2695420800000, 34786.43667767599], [2698012800000, 34786.43667767599], [2700691200000, 34786.43667767599], [2703369600000, 34786.43667767599], [2705961600000, 34786.43667767599], [2708640000000, 35647.95960199275], [2711232000000, 35647.95960199275], [2713910400000, 35648.33720051777], [2716588800000, 35648.33720051777], [2719094400000, 35648.33720051777], [2721772800000, 35648.33720051777], [2724364800000, 35648.33720051777], [2727043200000, 35648.33720051777], [2729635200000, 35648.33720051777], [2732313600000, 35648.33720051777], [2734992000000, 35648.33720051777], [2737584000000, 35648.33720051777], [2740262400000, 325.8973035307899], [2742854400000, 325.8973035307899], [2745532800000, 326.27679004844384], [2748211200000, 326.27679004844384], [2750630400000, 326.27679004844384], [2753308800000, 326.27679004844384], [2755900800000, 326.27679004844384], [2758579200000, 326.27679004844384], [2761171200000, 326.27679004844384], [2763849600000, 326.27679004844384], [2766528000000, 326.27679004844384], [2769120000000, 326.27679004844384], [2771798400000, 326.27679004844384], [2774390400000, 326.27679004844384], [2777068800000, 326.65817399868604], [2779747200000, 326.65817399868604], [2782166400000, 326.65817399868604], [2784844800000, 326.65817399868604], [2787436800000, 326.65817399868604], [2790115200000, 326.65817399868604], [2792707200000, 326.65817399868604], [2795385600000, 326.65817399868604], [2798064000000, 326.65817399868604], [2800656000000, 326.65817399868604], [2803334400000, 326.65817399868604], [2805926400000, 326.65817399868604], [2808604800000, 327.04146486867944], [2811283200000, 327.04146486867944], [2813702400000, 327.04146486867944], [2816380800000, 327.04146486867944], [2818972800000, 327.04146486867944], [2821651200000, 327.04146486867944], [2824243200000, 327.04146486867944], [2826921600000, 327.04146486867944], [2829600000000, 327.04146486867944], [2832192000000, 327.04146486867944], [2834870400000, 327.04146486867944], [2837462400000, 327.04146486867944], [2840140800000, 327.42667219302285], [2842819200000, 327.42667219302285], [2845324800000, 327.42667219302285], [2848003200000, 327.42667219302285], [2850595200000, 327.42667219302285], [2853273600000, 327.42667219302285], [2855865600000, 327.42667219302285], [2858544000000, 327.42667219302285], [2861222400000, 327.42667219302285], [2863814400000, 327.42667219302285], [2866492800000, 327.42667219302285], [2869084800000, 327.42667219302285], [2871763200000, 327.81380555398795], [2874441600000, 327.81380555398795], [2876860800000, 327.81380555398795], [2879539200000, 327.81380555398795], [2882131200000, 327.81380555398795], [2884809600000, 327.81380555398795], [2887401600000, 327.81380555398795], [2890080000000, 327.81380555398795], [2892758400000, 327.81380555398795], [2895350400000, 327.81380555398795], [2898028800000, 327.81380555398795], [2900620800000, 327.81380555398795], [2903299200000, 328.2028745817579], [2905977600000, 328.2028745817579], [2908396800000, 328.2028745817579], [2911075200000, 328.2028745817579], [2913667200000, 328.2028745817579], [2916345600000, 328.2028745817579], [2918937600000, 328.2028745817579], [2921616000000, 328.2028745817579], [2924294400000, 328.2028745817579], [2926886400000, 328.2028745817579], [2929564800000, 328.2028745817579], [2932156800000, 328.2028745817579], [2934835200000, 328.5938889546667], [2937513600000, 328.5938889546667], [2939932800000, 328.5938889546667], [2942611200000, 328.5938889546667], [2945203200000, 328.5938889546667], [2947881600000, 328.5938889546667], [2950473600000, 328.5938889546667], [2953152000000, 328.5938889546667], [2955830400000, 328.5938889546667], [2958422400000, 328.5938889546667], [2961100800000, 328.5938889546667], [2963692800000, 328.5938889546667], [2966371200000, 328.98685839944], [2969049600000, 328.98685839944], [2971555200000, 328.98685839944], [2974233600000, 328.98685839944], [2976825600000, 328.98685839944], [2979504000000, 328.98685839944], [2982096000000, 328.98685839944], [2984774400000, 328.98685839944], [2987452800000, 328.98685839944], [2990044800000, 328.98685839944], [2992723200000, 328.98685839944], [2995315200000, 328.98685839944], [2997993600000, 329.38179269143717], [3000672000000, 329.38179269143717], [3003091200000, 329.38179269143717], [3005769600000, 329.38179269143717], [3008361600000, 329.38179269143717], [3011040000000, 329.38179269143717], [3013632000000, 329.38179269143717], [3016310400000, 329.38179269143717], [3018988800000, 329.38179269143717], [3021580800000, 329.38179269143717], [3024259200000, 329.38179269143717], [3026851200000, 329.38179269143717], [3029529600000, 329.77870165489435], [3032208000000, 329.77870165489435], [3034627200000, 329.77870165489435], [3037305600000, 329.77870165489435], [3039897600000, 329.77870165489435], [3042576000000, 329.77870165489435], [3045168000000, 329.77870165489435], [3047846400000, 329.77870165489435], [3050524800000, 329.77870165489435], [3053116800000, 329.77870165489435], [3055795200000, 329.77870165489435], [3058387200000, 329.77870165489435], [3061065600000, 330.1775951631688], [3063744000000, 330.1775951631688], [3066163200000, 330.1775951631688], [3068841600000, 330.1775951631688], [3071433600000, 330.1775951631688], [3074112000000, 330.1775951631688], [3076704000000, 330.1775951631688], [3079382400000, 330.1775951631688], [3082060800000, 330.1775951631688], [3084652800000, 330.1775951631688], [3087331200000, 330.1775951631688], [3089923200000, 330.1775951631688], [3092601600000, 330.57848313898467], [3095280000000, 330.57848313898467], [3097785600000, 330.57848313898467], [3100464000000, 330.57848313898467], [3103056000000, 330.57848313898467], [3105734400000, 330.57848313898467], [3108326400000, 330.57848313898467], [3111004800000, 330.57848313898467], [3113683200000, 330.57848313898467], [3116275200000, 330.57848313898467], [3118953600000, 330.57848313898467], [3121545600000, 330.57848313898467], [3124224000000, 330.9813755546796], [3126902400000, 330.9813755546796], [3129321600000, 330.9813755546796], [3132000000000, 330.9813755546796], [3134592000000, 330.9813755546796], [3137270400000, 330.9813755546796], [3139862400000, 330.9813755546796], [3142540800000, 330.9813755546796], [3145219200000, 330.9813755546796], [3147811200000, 330.9813755546796], [3150489600000, 330.9813755546796], [3153081600000, 330.9813755546796], [3155760000000, 331.38628243245296], [3158438400000, 331.38628243245296], [3160857600000, 331.38628243245296], [3163536000000, 331.38628243245296], [3166128000000, 331.38628243245296], [3168806400000, 331.38628243245296], [3171398400000, 331.38628243245296], [3174076800000, 331.38628243245296], [3176755200000, 331.38628243245296], [3179347200000, 331.38628243245296], [3182025600000, 331.38628243245296], [3184617600000, 331.38628243245296], [3187296000000, 331.7932138446152], [3189974400000, 331.7932138446152], [3192393600000, 331.7932138446152], [3195072000000, 331.7932138446152], [3197664000000, 331.7932138446152], [3200342400000, 331.7932138446152], [3202934400000, 331.7932138446152], [3205612800000, 331.7932138446152], [3208291200000, 331.7932138446152], [3210883200000, 331.7932138446152], [3213561600000, 331.7932138446152], [3216153600000, 331.7932138446152], [3218832000000, 332.2021799138383], [3221510400000, 332.2021799138383], [3224016000000, 332.2021799138383], [3226694400000, 332.2021799138383], [3229286400000, 332.2021799138383], [3231964800000, 332.2021799138383], [3234556800000, 332.2021799138383], [3237235200000, 332.2021799138383], [3239913600000, 332.2021799138383], [3242505600000, 332.2021799138383], [3245184000000, 332.2021799138383], [3247776000000, 332.2021799138383], [3250454400000, 332.61319081340747], [3253132800000, 332.61319081340747], [3255552000000, 332.61319081340747], [3258230400000, 332.61319081340747], [3260822400000, 332.61319081340747], [3263500800000, 332.61319081340747], [3266092800000, 332.61319081340747], [3268771200000, 332.61319081340747], [3271449600000, 332.61319081340747], [3274041600000, 332.61319081340747], [3276720000000, 332.61319081340747], [3279312000000, 332.61319081340747], [3281990400000, 333.0262567674745], [3284668800000, 333.0262567674745], [3287088000000, 333.0262567674745], [3289766400000, 333.0262567674745], [3292358400000, 333.0262567674745], [3295036800000, 333.0262567674745], [3297628800000, 333.0262567674745], [3300307200000, 333.0262567674745], [3302985600000, 333.0262567674745], [3305577600000, 333.0262567674745], [3308256000000, 333.0262567674745], [3310848000000, 333.0262567674745], [3313526400000, 333.44138805131183], [3316204800000, 333.44138805131183], [3318624000000, 333.44138805131183], [3321302400000, 333.44138805131183], [3323894400000, 333.44138805131183], [3326572800000, 333.44138805131183], [3329164800000, 333.44138805131183], [3331843200000, 333.44138805131183], [3334521600000, 333.44138805131183], [3337113600000, 333.44138805131183], [3339792000000, 333.44138805131183], [3342384000000, 333.44138805131183], [3345062400000, 333.8585949915684], [3347740800000, 333.8585949915684], [3350246400000, 333.8585949915684], [3352924800000, 333.8585949915684], [3355516800000, 333.8585949915684], [3358195200000, 333.8585949915684], [3360787200000, 333.8585949915684], [3363465600000, 333.8585949915684], [3366144000000, 333.8585949915684], [3368736000000, 333.8585949915684], [3371414400000, 333.8585949915684], [3374006400000, 333.8585949915684], [3376684800000, 334.27788796652624], [3379363200000, 334.27788796652624], [3381782400000, 334.27788796652624], [3384460800000, 334.27788796652624], [3387052800000, 334.27788796652624], [3389731200000, 334.27788796652624], [3392323200000, 334.27788796652624], [3395001600000, 334.27788796652624], [3397680000000, 334.27788796652624], [3400272000000, 334.27788796652624], [3402950400000, 334.27788796652624], [3405542400000, 334.27788796652624], [3408220800000, 334.6992774063589], [3410899200000, 334.6992774063589], [3413318400000, 334.6992774063589], [3415996800000, 334.6992774063589], [3418588800000, 334.6992774063589], [3421267200000, 334.6992774063589], [3423859200000, 334.6992774063589], [3426537600000, 334.6992774063589], [3429216000000, 334.6992774063589], [3431808000000, 334.6992774063589], [3434486400000, 334.6992774063589], [3437078400000, 334.6992774063589], [3439756800000, 335.12277379339065], [3442435200000, 335.12277379339065], [3444854400000, 335.12277379339065], [3447532800000, 335.12277379339065], [3450124800000, 335.12277379339065], [3452803200000, 335.12277379339065], [3455395200000, 335.12277379339065], [3458073600000, 335.12277379339065], [3460752000000, 335.12277379339065], [3463344000000, 335.12277379339065], [3466022400000, 335.12277379339065], [3468614400000, 335.12277379339065], [3471292800000, 335.5483876623576], [3473971200000, 335.5483876623576], [3476476800000, 335.5483876623576], [3479155200000, 335.5483876623576], [3481747200000, 335.5483876623576], [3484425600000, 335.5483876623576], [3487017600000, 335.5483876623576], [3489696000000, 335.5483876623576], [3492374400000, 335.5483876623576], [3494966400000, 335.5483876623576], [3497644800000, 335.5483876623576], [3500236800000, 335.5483876623576], [3502915200000, 335.97612960066937], [3505593600000, 335.97612960066937], [3508012800000, 335.97612960066937], [3510691200000, 335.97612960066937], [3513283200000, 335.97612960066937], [3515961600000, 335.97612960066937], [3518553600000, 335.97612960066937], [3521232000000, 335.97612960066937], [3523910400000, 335.97612960066937], [3526502400000, 335.97612960066937], [3529180800000, 335.97612960066937], [3531772800000, 335.97612960066937]]
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tmj3fLhv/

Is there any possibility to prevent Highcharts from grouping data to more than one year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your setting of [`groupPixelWidth`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth) that is making this difficult. It is trying to group by the amount of pixels instead of times.

Therefore, by removing the `groupPixelWidth` setting, and setting units to `year, [1]`, the chart will behave as you expect.

```
series: [{
  dataGrouping: {
    units: [
      ['month', [1,6]],
      ['year', [1]]
    ]
  },
  ...
}]
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/tmj3fLhv/13/

If you set the `groupPixelWidth` because you wanted the columns to be a certain width, you should instead use pointWidth.

Comment: That works! But if I only want to display full years or only one month the switch from showing years to showing months happens in the middle of the range so that you have a lot of month showing. I would like to show years and in a time range of  10 years I would like to switch to showing months.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. When should it show months? When there is 12 months in view, when there is 36, 120? When should it show years, when there is 1 year, 10 years? How should these be grouped?

Comment: sorry for the complicated description. I would like to see a maximum of 120 months, if there are more than 120 month it should change to years. The data is always month based.